# Integrate $\int \frac {\ln x}{x^2}$ by U-Substitution

Tags: integration, proof-verification

I've got a question regarding "improper" u-substitution integrals.

How would we solve
$\int \frac {\ln(x)}{x^2}dx$
using the u-substitution $u = \ln(x)$?

I know that it might be easier to solve it by parts instead, but just humor me, please.

Going by u-substitution, we'd get

$$\int \frac {u}{x^2}dx, u = \ln(x), du = \frac1x dx$$

That would lead us to

$$\int (\frac 1x \bullet u)\ du$$

The issue is with the $\frac 1x$ in that integral. I'm not entirely sure how to proceed from here.

My thoughts are to go with

$$u = ln(x) => e^u = e^{\ln(x)} = x$$

then

$$\int (\frac 1x \bullet u)\ du = \int (e^{-u} \bullet u) \ du$$

Integrating by parts

$$f = u , \ df = 1, \ g = -e^{-u}, \ dg = e^{-u}$$

$$\int (u \bullet e^{-u}) \ du = -e^{-u} \bullet u \ - \int (-e^{-u}) \ du$$

$$\int (u \bullet e^{-u}) \ du = -e^{-u} \bullet u \ + \int (e^{-u}) \ du$$

$$\int (u \bullet e^{-u}) \ du = -e^{-u} \bullet u \ - \ (e^{-u}) \ du$$

$$\int (u \bullet e^{-u}) \ du = -e^{-u} (u + 1) = -\frac {(u + 1)}{e^u}$$

Substituting $u = ln(x)$ back in,

$$-\frac {(u + 1)}{e^u} = - \frac{\ln(x) + 1}{x}$$

Does everything look right with what I did? Solving the integral by parts does get the final answer by u-substitution, but I want to make sure I'm done everything right.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You forgot the $+C$.

Comment: When doing $u$-substitution, you shouldn't write down an integral containing $u$'s and $x$'s. Once you make the substitution, you should substitute everything. (It's okay to figure it out in steps, but when writing it up, for example, you should go straight from $\int\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2}dx$ to $\int e^{-u}u du$, with a side note that $u=\ln(x)$, $x=e^u$, and $du=\frac{1}{x}dx$). Also, $df=du$ and $dg=e^{-u}du$ (you just left off the $du$'s). And of course $+C$ at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why starting with a substitution, since you have to use integration by parts anyway.

However, you should remove $x$ altogether, otherwise you might overlook something: if $u=\ln x$, then $x=e^u$ and $dx=e^u\,du$, so you get
$$
\int \frac{u}{e^{2u}}e^u\,du=\int ue^{-u}\,du
$$
Integrating by parts,
$$
\int ue^{-u}\,du=-ue^{-u}+\int e^{-u}\,du=
-\frac{u}{e^u}-\frac{1}{e^u}+C=-\frac{1+\ln x}{x}+C
$$
Directly integrating by parts is easier:
$$
\int\frac{\ln x}{x^2}\,dx=-\frac{1}{x}\ln x+\int\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx
=-\frac{1}{x}\ln x-\frac{1}{x}+C
$$
and you can see that the substitution is just adding noise, because you do exactly the same steps. You gain nothing at all or, maybe, some occasion for making a mistake. `;-)`

A better substitution could be $\frac{1}{x}=u$, so $x=u^{-1}$ and the integral becomes
$$
\int u^2\ln(u^{-1})\frac{-1}{u^2}\,du=\int\ln u\,du
$$
that can again be done by parts, but is surely among the “known” ones.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, this is correct (sort of).** However, I have three points to make.

1. Most importantly, you forgot the $+C$. Any antiderivative should have a constant on the end, with an unknown value (given other information, it *may* be possible to find this value).
2. I would be careful with how you write out your calculations where doing $u$-substitution. I tend to write it in two lines, like so:

   > $$f=u\quad \mathrm{d}f=1\cdot\mathrm{d}u\\\mathrm{d}g=e^{-u}\mathrm{d}u,\quad g=-e^{-u}$$

   This makes it just a bit neater. Of course, this is just my personal preference, but I find that it's a bit more organized.
3. I agree with [kccu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548793/integrate-int-frac-ln-xx2-by-u-substitution/1548816#comment3153920_1548793) that it might be good to not have $x$ and $u$ in the same integral. Sure, $u$ is a function of $x$ (and vice versa, here), but taken out of context, that might not be the case. Again, this is just something minor, but it makes the expression a bit neater.